# What does 别把这天的彩虹, 放在明天的天空 mean?

Tags: translation

I was reading this in an online dictionary.

> **别把这天的彩虹, 放在明天的天空**

I can translate it word by word but is it a saying/quote?

Comment: @happytime I didn't notice that it was i until you mentioned it........

Comment: If the original source for the phrase/quote can be provided, it might give some additional clues about how to interpret the meaning more accurately.

Comment: My view is, it is equivalent to the English -- "Don't rest on your laurels" In other words don't assume that the "rainbow", (achievements), you see (or attain), today would appear, (be attainable), again tomorrow or in the future.

Answer (score 4):

别把这天的彩虹放在明天的天空

Don't take today's rainbow and put it on tomorrow's sky.

It should mean something like:

If you are happy now, it doesn't mean you will still be happy in the future.
If things are good now, it doesn't mean they will still be in the future.

Or simply:
Things change.

Comment: what is the basis for this interpretation? users generally can make a reasonable guess, but most expect explanations based on Chinese language usage or literary traditions or perhaps based on 雷松's own writings or interviews 这种解释的基础是什么呢？所有用户都可以作出某种差不多合理的猜测，但是大多数用户期望的是从汉语言的使用或文学传统方面的解释,基于雷松自己的作品或访谈也可以

Comment: @S.Rhee It's based on my own interpretation. The asker didn't know what it meant so I tried to help. But I can delete it if it's against the site rules giving one's own opinion. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

This is my personal opinion. For me, this sentence shares the same meaning as a much more famous quote 今朝有酒今朝醉, which tells you to enjoy your life when you can. Or say we should live for today, but not for tomorrow.

Edit: Ach, thanks to @S.Rhee, it might be a bad interpretation to understand this quote and 今朝有酒今朝醉 here. 
Considering the fact that this quote is mentioned in the 尝试 page on Baidu Baike. It might be reasonable to read it as "do it now" or "try it now".

Comment: see iciba for 今朝有酒今朝醉

Answer (score 1):

别把这天的彩虹放在明天的天空

Not a well known saying. Maybe a quote from somewhere.

Don't put this day's rainbow in tomorrows sky.

Whatever that means!

Comment: yeah,i translated it that way too but i am not sure what it means..........thanks for answering though!

Comment: quotation from 雷松 see
http://www.baike.com/wiki/%E5%B0%9D%E8%AF%95

http://www.zhengjicn.com/mingyan/44169.html 关于尝试的名人名言 famous quotes about trying，

Comment: To find out who 雷松 is look this name （word） up in iciba， at the bottom find article from 百科 along with picture

Comment: I did find it from baike.com, however i cannot understand what it means......maybe don't stop trying just because you achieved something today, or something like that....? Thank you!!!

Comment: @stella_t that's basically what it means. You can also understand it like just because you achieved something great before it doesn't mean you are still that great now. In other words, don't stop trying

Comment: Maybe 'Don't just assume tomorrow will be fine.'

Answer (score 0):

I actually liked [this interpretation](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/160023547.html) that I found on Baidu:

> 从表面看可以翻译成 今天的彩虹就在今天绽放

> 我自己的理解是： 不要耽误大好的时光，就在当下毫无保留的绽放自己的光芒。

I think this intended to be a positive/inspirational quote, so the tone of the phrase should be one that is encouraging rather than forewarning the changes that might be ahead.

The popular Latin expression of [carpe diem](https://www.britannica.com/topic/carpe-diem) - literally 'pluck the day' comes to mind when talking about seizing the most of an opportunity and making it count, without giving too much thought to tomorrow.